# Kubernetes (docker-desktop) with multiple LoadBalancer services

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

Is it true that I cannot have two LoadBalancer services on a docker-desktop cluster (osx), because they would both use `localhost` (and all ports are forwarded)?

I created an example and the latter service is never assigned an external IP address but stays in state `pending`. However, the former is accessible on localhost.

```
> kubectl get all     
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/whoami-deployment-9f9c86c4f-l5lkj      1/1     Running   0          28s
pod/whoareyou-deployment-b896ddb9c-lncdm   1/1     Running   0          27s
pod/whoareyou-deployment-b896ddb9c-s72sc   1/1     Running   0          27s

NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes          ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        95s
service/whoami-service      LoadBalancer   10.97.171.139   localhost     80:30024/TCP   27s
service/whoareyou-service   LoadBalancer   10.97.171.204   <pending>     80:32083/TCP   27s

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/whoami-deployment      1/1     1            1           28s
deployment.apps/whoareyou-deployment   2/2     2            2           27s

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/whoami-deployment-9f9c86c4f      1         1         1       28s
replicaset.apps/whoareyou-deployment-b896ddb9c   2         2         2       27s
```

Detailed state fo whoareyou-service:

```
kubectl describe service whoareyou-service
Name:                     whoareyou-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"whoareyou-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name...
Selector:                 app=whoareyou
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.106.5.8
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30333/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.209:80,10.1.0.210:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: Could you `describe service whoareyou-service` ?

Comment: Can you access the two NodePort ports `localhost:30024` and `localhost:32083`, from the console on the same physical host?  I'm pretty sure the Docker desktop applications can't actually produce a load balancer for LoadBalancer-type services and so they'll act just like NodePort services.

Comment: @DavidMaze you mean like with Minikube, which does not really support LoadBalancers at all? But no, I can't access them.

Comment: @mario I added the output to the question

Comment: It works probably exacly the same way as in `Minikube`. As `docker-desktop` is unable to provision real `LoadBalancer` it can still "simulate" creating service of such type using `NodePort` (this can easily be seen from port range it uses). I'm pretty sure you cannot use same IP address as the `ExternalIP` of the `LoadBalancer` service and if you create one more `Service` of such type, your docker-desktop has no other choice than to use your localhost one more time. As it is already used by another `Service` it cannot be used by another one and that's why it remains in a pending state.

Comment: Note that if you create real `LoadBalancer` in a cloud environment, each time new IP is provisioned and there is no situation that next `LoadBalancer` you create gets the same IP that is already used by the existing one. Apparently here it cannot use any other IP then localhost, and this one is already in use. Anyway I would recommend you to simply use `NodePort` if you want to expose your `Deployment` to the external world.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to copy my comments, as they partially explain the problem, and make a `Community Wiki` answer out of them so it is more clearly seen and available for possible further edits by the Community:

It works probably exactly the same way as in **Minikube**. As **docker-desktop** is unable to provision real `LoadBalancer` it can still "simulate" creating `Service` of such type using `NodePort` (this can easily be seen from port range it uses). I'm pretty sure you cannot use same IP address as the `ExternalIP` of the `LoadBalancer` `Service` and if you create one more `Service` of such type, your **docker-desktop** has no other choice than to use your localhost one more time. As it is already used by one `Service` it cannot be used by another one and that's why it remains in a `pending state`.

Note that if you create real `LoadBalancer` in a cloud environment, each time new IP is provisioned and there is no situation that next `LoadBalancer` you create gets the same IP that is already used by the existing one. Apparently here it cannot use any other IP then one of `localhost`, and this one is already in use. Anyway I would recommend you to simply use `NodePort` if you want to expose your `Deployment` to the external world.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using Ingress controller instead.

So basically, it's 3 steps after installing docker-desktop :

1. Wilcard Certificate locally
2. SSL certificate For local env
3. Install Ingress Controller

Detailed here: https://github.com/kubernetes-tn/guideline-kubernetes-enterprise/blob/master/general/desktop-env-setup.md

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while looking to set up a lightweight local environment with minimal dependencies.

I found that two `LoadBalancer` work on `localhost` when using different port numbers.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-one-lb
spec:
  ports:
    - name: 8081-tcp
      port: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: webapp-one
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-two-lb
spec:
  ports:
    - name: 8082-tcp
      port: 8082
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: webapp-two
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

As others have said, Ingress is more flexible and allows for sub-domain and path based routing without having to worry about port conflicts, but it comes with an additional learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

[Snapshot of All Available Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxGCR.png)

Well, I would like to add something to Mario's comment and subsequent answer. I am using Docker Desktop Kubernetes. In my case, the loadbalancer's external IP is not in pending state, rather same localhost got assigned with a different port. Nonetheless, I also tried using MetalLB, but so far couldn't change the default behavior.