# Kubernetes-Ingress - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

im trying to build my first kubernetes project. I followed this guide:

```
https://gitlab.com/codeching/kubernetes-multicontainer-application-react-nodejs-postgres-nginx
```

I did apply ingress-nginx:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.46.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

and `kubectl apply -f k8s`

But when im trying to get localhost i get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
Does anyone know why?

```
kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx

NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.101.205.135   localhost     80:31831/TCP,443:32609/TCP   7h53m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.107.145.81    <none>        443/TCP                      7h53m


kubectl get ingress ingress-service 
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-service   <none>   *                 80      13m


kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx

NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-tns5w        0/1     Completed   0          24m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-78vhj         0/1     Completed   1          24m
ingress-nginx-controller-686556747b-kd4tn   1/1     Running     0          24m
```

Comment: Check the pods of your namespace to see if they're crashing. The ingress might be trying to route to the pods and the pods are't started properly: `kubectl get pods -n {namespace}`

Comment: ingress-nginx-controller-686556747b-kd4tn   1/1     Running     0          24m
ingress-nginx-admission-create-tns5w        0/1     Completed   0          24m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-78vhj         0/1     Completed   1          24m

Comment: nginx-controller is running, the admission-create and admission-patch have status completed

Comment: no, I meant the pods for your nodejs service. You _have_ deployed the nodejs service, right? Otherwise, the ingress is trying to send traffic to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @BlenderFox this is what i get affter running `kubetl get all` https://imgur.com/a/VQpCnYf

Comment: That's good, that shows your services. Is this a different namespace to your ingress? Note that ingresses and the services the ingresses route for, must be in the same namespace. However. the actual ingress controller can be in another namespace

Comment: No, there are no other namespaces.

Comment: Please add the output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`, `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces`, and `kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces` (use a pastebin link or similar if needed) - this will let us see what is running and where. Redact any lines that are confidential or similar.

Comment: @BlenderFox https://pastebin.com/q0jLK0ci

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of `kubectl get ingress -n development ingress-service -o yaml` and `kubectl get pod -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller-686556747b-zm8qs`

Comment: @BlenderFox https://pastebin.com/K3qcZHut . Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: No problem. So your ingress is in the same namespace as your service, which is good. It's also pointing at `client-cluster-ip-service:3000` which also agrees with your service. Next thing to try to is to port-forward the client port and try to see what the ingress is seeing.  Run `kubectl port-forward -n development svc/client-cluster-ip-service 3000:3000` . This will open a proxy from `localhost:3000` to the service on your cluster. Open `localhost:3000` in a browser and see if you get anything.

Comment: Additionally, I believe (but I am unsure as I'm not a node developer), that 3000 is the port used by node apps. So you could also get the logs for your client pod using `kubectl logs -f -n development client-deployment-b56847967-g9jds`

Comment: @BlenderFox after port forward i can finally enter the app on localhost:3000, although the backend is not working. https://imgur.com/a/zj1pcWa. Kubect logs: https://pastebin.com/VnxbYBuJ

Comment: That looks like a nodejs error, and unfortunately not something I am too familiar with.

Comment: Okay, but why i cannot open the app on localhost:80?

Comment: @BlenderFox Isn't it somehow connected to nginx? Because the app should oppen on localhost:80, and the backend should get/post requests on localhost:80/api/values, but after port-forward it changes 80 to 3000

Comment: Are you running kubernetes as a local cluster or in a managed service like GKE or AKS?

Comment: @BlendyFox local cluster

Comment: And one thing i  noticed is that  ingress-nginx-controller   have status <pending>

Comment: I think that if app would open normally on localhost:80, the backend would work as well.

Comment: Are you using minikube?

Comment: @BlenderFox no, im not using minikube

Comment: Which method are you using to generate your local cluster?

Comment: @BlenderFox What do you mean? Im using Docker Desktop with Kubernetes turned on

Comment: Okay, that is what I meant. There's different ways to spin up a local cluster and for example, with minikube you need to have another process running to generate the load balancer IPs for you. As for Docker Desktop with Kubernetes, if your LB is still showing <pending> you should run a `kubectl describe` on that service to see if there's any errors in the event log. That should hopefully be able to point you in the right direction. This would also explain why your attempt to use `localhost:80` didn't work -- because it was not connected successfully -- maybe something else is using the port?

Comment: @BlenderFox kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx : https://pastebin.com/5JxcCdLB

Comment: Right so I'm not sure about docker-desktop, but on minikube, loadbalancers can't be created unless you have a tunnel open (https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel). I am not sure about docker-desktop, but perhaps something similar is used. As an alternative you can either change the service type of the ingress controller from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort` (which will assign a random free port on your node -- which is your local machine, then you use that as localhost:xxxx), or portforward like we did earlier.

Comment: Also, this question might be of relevantce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412733/kubernetes-docker-desktop-with-multiple-loadbalancer-services, specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412733/kubernetes-docker-desktop-with-multiple-loadbalancer-services#comment105041112_59412733

Comment: @BlenderFox it does not even work on NodePort.. I am done.